# Is it possible that the literal presentation of scripture alone somewhat diminishes the dynamic nature of God’s living Word?

Tags: inspiration

Matthew 13:9, (and also a number of other references) mentioned “having ears to hear, let him hear”. Jesus finds it important enough to mention on several occasion. As if to say read between the lines. (Of course that is my interpretation…lol) That seems To suggest interpretation is beyond literal boundaries alone. Being of one spirit and one body would perhaps minimize ambiguity.

Comment: No, it wasnt suggesting any hidden or between the lines meaning, but that only the wise understands this. The parables were sometimes meant to be an indirect reproach to the religious hypocrite. This has nothing to do with scripture alone. You can talk about the dictation theory of inspiration (and inerrancy) as a hurdle for proper interpretation which takes away the real nature of the writings. Such doctrine narrows down the scope of hermeneutics.

Comment: Is it the spirit of God or worldly wisdom allowing us to comprehend? Full Truth and revelation can be book knowledge alone, wisdom of the world?

Comment: Sola scripture doesn't mean truth and revelation can be from the bible alone. We believe the living Holy spirit and its working in our lives the same way it worked in the writers of the bible. Sola scripture only means rejection of extra biblical tradition; that the bible alone is sufficient and sole authority. Just a formal fence against man made tradition.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.  This question needs a specific Bible verse to analyze.

Answer (score 1):

It may be *"reading between the lines"* that has caused so many arguments and conflicts in religious circles over the centuries! What Jesus was saying in Matthew 13:9 is clarified by him in the verses following. His disciples heard him say, "Who has ears to hear, let him listen." (A.V.) This caused the puzzled disciples to ask him why, therefore, he spoke to the crowds in parables. Now, parables are not meant to be taken literally. They are invented little stories that are based in real life, but the characters and the events are fictional. The idea of a parable is to teach a truth via a little story that will make the important points needed to understand what the speaker is getting at. They can teach when the listeners relate to the reality of the story, knowing such things can and do happen in real life. But they must learn the lesson - the point - by thinking about what the principle is. They will only be able to do that if they truly listen (or read, in our case) with a heart genuinely desiring to know God's truth. That is what Jesus went on to say, and **the quote that follows is the answer to your question:**

> "It is given unto you to know the mysteries of the kingdom of heaven,
> but to them it is not given.
>
> For whosoever hath, to him shall be given, and he shall have more
> abundance; but whosoever hath not, from him shall be taken away even
> that he hath.
>
> Therefore speak I unto them in parables: because they seeing see not;
> and hearing they hear not, neither do they understand.
>
> And in them is fulfilled the prophecy of Esaias, which saith, 'By
> hearing ye shall hear, and shall not understand: and seeing ye shall
> see, and shall not perceive;
>
> For this people's heart is waxed gross, and their ears are dull of
> hearing, and their eyes they have closed; lest at any time they should
> see with their eyes, and hear with their ears, and should understand
> with their heart, and should be converted, and I should heal them.
>
> But blessed are your eyes, for they see: and your ears, for they
> hear." (Matthew 13:11-16)

So ***yes, there is a sense in which scripture alone, presented literally, can diminish the dynamic nature of God's living word. That is because God's word only comes alive when the Holy Spirit that inspired it opens up its meaning to sincere seekers after God's truth.*** Until that Spirit-breathed word is Spirit-interpreted, there can only be human attempts at "reading between the lines" which will just result in a plethora of different interpretations and understandings (or, no understanding at all.) The living word gives life to those who are alive by the power of the living Spirit. Only the Holy Spirit's interpretation is valid.

Jesus promised just that before he returned to heaven - see John 14:15-17 & 25; & 15:26.

Answer (score 0):

“having ears to hear, let him hear”

This comes after the parable of the sower. A brief explanation of how God's word is given to the world - some, only a portion, are able to receive it. The rest is not wasted - God wastes nothing. To think God wastes is to think He has made an error, a mistake.

And so the phrase, “having ears to hear, let him hear”, is to focus on the ones who *can* receive the word (seed) and do something with it - be part of the growth it is designed for.

This is the wonder of God bringing about salvation - who desires none be lost.

> The Lord is not slow about His promise, as some count slowness, but is patient toward you, not willing for any to perish, but for all to come to repentance.

There is a hint there that the parameters of *who* gets salvation and (apparently), who *seems* not to is just a matter of time. God's provision is for all - eventually this will be understood by those yet to see - or hear.

Those who *can* hear, are expected to *act on that gift* - to *participate* in their own salvation process. This is comparable to Jesus' journey - he was perfected, made complete, by his suffering. Only by that process of him surrendering his own will in obedient subjection to God, could his mission be accomplished. We too, are on a similar journey - to hear, to trust and to do - to live out the new reality of being heavenly and not worldly. Jesus referring to the disciples similarly -

> They are not of the world, just as I am not of the world. John 17:16

There is always a choice, a willing subjection to 'hear'. God gives us the ears - opens the ears to hear. Yet the hearing is up to us - what is hearing without doing?  Even doing is of little value unless it is *done* by faith.

> But don’t just listen to God’s word. You must do what it says. Otherwise, you are only fooling yourselves. James 1:22

The dynamic nature of the written word, only when coupled with God's spirit does something within us that allows understanding, and Godly wisdom - much more than knowledge alone. Millions have read and have *known* the Bible, but have never gained the understanding made possible by God's spirit being present.

When God’s spirit *is* present in a believer, it does not guarantee complete truth or understanding in this age, but this is secondary to the heart which is the important matter before God.